# struts 2 actions coupled to pages?

Tags: struts2

### Problem

While developing struts2 application I was asked to implement two pages: the one listing current user's books and the other listing current user's CDs. So I decided to implement two struts2 actions: ListBooks and ListCDs, both of them having standard dispatch result type, pointing to corresponding JSP pages.

Later the client changed his mind and decided that both lists of books and CDs should reside on the same page. So how can I reuse my actions so that I wouldn't need to rewrite any classes.

### My attempt

First approach was to use action chaining. So that both actions can contribute their properties to value stack. But then there is a problem: we establish some unnatural order for actions. If I chain ListBooks to ListCDs then invoking ListCDs on its own causes some erroneous behavior - as it will result in a page where both books and CDs should be listed.

Another way was to use action tags. But I don't like it either as it forces separation of my page into multiple JSP parts and generally feels like doing things not in struts2 style.

### Questions

So how do I combine my actions to form single page in a "clean way"? The problem seems to be so simple.

Another question spawned by this problem is about struts2 design - do struts2 actions take too much responsibility? Apart from being "single units of work" they are also coupled to presentation level. Everytime I change the structure of my pages I have to think about redesigning my actions. Am I missing something or struts2 really has this type of design weakness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts 2 actions only take too much responsibility if they're designed that way--they should act as a thin bridge between the web and business layers.

Each of the earlier actions should have just had a service to retrieve the items in question. The new action would have both services, and expose the results of the user's books and CDs to the view layer.

Of course they're coupled to the presentation level--they are what determines what's available to the view. In any action-based framework this is the case, whether it's the action itself, the model in a `ModelDriven` action, a Spring MVC controller returning a view, a Struts 1 action form, request attributes, etc.

The amount of work necessary to support the type of change you describe is almost nothing: move the service from one action to another, and either expose the additional results directly, or add them to the exposed model.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. That was a complete answer. Strange that some guys (including authors of "Struts 2 in action") advocate using actions not as a thin layer but as the place for application logic.

Comment: I've read "Struts 2 in Action" and didn't find it suggested that.  There was an effort to create such abstraction with the "PortfolioService" used in the book.  The chapter which covers spring then explains how that can be taken further with DI. If used as a reference book this could be easily missed but the in action series is designed to be rather readable.  I would love to see a new Web Application book covering struts2 the more common plugins spring, hibernate and touching on client side scripting (preferably with jQuery). In other words a merging of Daves and Scotts books

Comment: @Quaternion In theory, I'm working on it, but it's a solo effort that's been put on hold several times. It's only recently I've had time to start revisiting it.

Comment: @Quaternion There are several places they advocate doing so: in "1.3.2" they write that Action is Model from MVC (while it is supposed to be part of the controller), later they continue with "Since the data is held local to the action, it’s always conveniently available during the execution of the business logic."

Comment: @pavel_kazlou I've never liked to think of struts2 as a MVC framework.  It's all the rage in Web frameworks, so it must be pure goodness. If I as a s2 user were to try to identify the MVC components I would say: The interceptor stack is the controller, the value stack is the model and the view is what ever renders the page (JSP, velocity, freemarker).  Architecturally that may not be correct but as a user those are the parts that I have direct control over. An action is just a path though these parts and the action class offers the user of s2 the opportunity to go pick some more stuff.

Comment: The action class is a marshaling spot for objects on their way to the view (really on their way to the value stack first, probably the largest tributary but not necessarily the only one), as such it is cleanest if that is all we see (by delegating processing logic to the service layer, which will remain clean by only having processing logic and and minimizing DB/storage logic by delegating that to the DB tier). Since s2 using the action mostly as a storage spot (first setting attributes from the request and then later storing what will be displayed to the view) it does mostly look like a model

Comment: You stated that the action class(AC) looks more like a controller. The easiest way to arrive at this conclusion is to think of the responsibility of the action in terms of your own logic: That is the AC _may_ be a controller with respect to your service layer but in terms of S2 it is not.  I've seen a number of people puzzling over s2 and mvc but it's about as useful as considering the evolutionary branches of ungulates in order to buy beef.  Seriously every new s2 developer must waste at a minimum 15min trying to understand s2 in terms of mvc.  S2IA is very responsible for this silliness...

Comment: As it has several sections dedicated to it which can be readily see in both its TOC and index. Take Daves book... not one reference in the TOC or index to MVC, which is better in comparison.  The only way it could be improved since this does come up a bit is if he did put a section in adding an "explanation" that is isn't a particularly useful to think in terms of MVC and why, rather than a rant like I just did.

Comment: @Quaternion is this the book you talking about? http://www.amazon.com/Apache-Struts-Web-Application-Development/dp/1847193390

Should I consider buying it if I already have Struts 2 in action?

Comment: When I said that AC is part of controller, I was considering MVC pattern applied to the whole application where S2 is just web front-end. But you can have other UI, for example command-line. So both S2 and command-line will provide their own View and Controller. But model (service layer with business logic) stays the same. But I get your point

Comment: @pavel_kazlou I like both books and think they are complementary, I was better off having both.

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ Look forward to seeing your next book.  If you are every looking for another reviewer, I'd love to look it over!

Comment: @pavel_kazlou The book is specifically different than S2iA, and covers S2.1. It's more of a complete web-app development book, however; only the first half is *specifically* Struts 2, the rest is general development. (And IMO the editing and indexing left a *lot* to be desired, which I found incredibly frustrating.)

Comment: @Quaternion I'll keep you in mind--thanks for the offer. I'd definitely like to cover some of the changes in the framework and delve into the internals since that's where most of the fun is.